# Missing mysqld.sock file on linux server

Tags: mysql, linux

I have this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Does anyone know what is wrong? It seems it isn't installing `mysqld.sock` when I run `apt-get install mysql-server`. I tried `find / -name "mysqld.sock"` but it can't find anything. How can I get `mysqld.sock`?

Comment: Did you start the mysql server? Is it configured to use a unix socket at that path?

Answer (score 2):

It should not install `mysqld.sock`. This file is a [unix socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), it doesn't refer to a byte stream on your hard disk.

It is more like a TCP port: programs can listen here, and other programs can connect it to communicate with it. The only significant different is that TCP ports are identified by a number between 1 and 65535. Unix sockets are identified by their path, like `/var/run/mysql/mysqld.sock`.

`mysqld.sock` is created by the mysql daemon on start, and it is removed (or, becomes un-connectable) if this daemon stops.

This message is given by some client process, trying to connect your mysqld on this socket without success.

Its most likely reason is that the mysqld doesn't run.

Why it doesn't run? Try to start it (`systemctl start mysqld`) and check the `/var/log/mysql*` .

Comment: in errror.log i've got this error.

2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in $2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2018-08-13 10:43:09 139999537754688 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Check what is listening on that socket with an `lsof -n -P|grep -F 3306|grep -F LISTEN`.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is created on MySQL service startup and deleted on stop.

Its missing because SQL has an issue starting.

Most common reason: Your drive is full.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to execute the following command

It's the same problem that  I faced recently when I tried to install `maraidb`, and it wouldn't start.

I used this command : `service mariadb start` .